# Is there a bundled library for regular expressions in MSVC?

Tags: c, regex, visual-c++

If I'm compiling a C program with gcc, I can safely assume that the functions in regex.h are available. Is there a regex library I can assume is there if someone is compiling with microsoft's C compiler?

Comment: Why is it safe to assume that?

Comment: Its as safe as compiling with unistd.h as a POSIX library and thats good enough for me. Unless a person is compiling under strange conditions, these libraries will be there.

Answer (score 1):

C++ only, but may be something you can use (or wrap):

Visual C++ 2010 includes the TR1 regex library support.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982382.aspx

It's also available for VC++ 2008 in a feature pack:

- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D466226B-8DAB-445F-A7B4-448B326C48E7&displaylang=en

Comment: I'm using <regex> on VC++ 2010 Express.

Comment: I just stumbled across a Bug in VC10 <regex>, there seem to be others too, when looking at the connect website. Maybe its worth looking at other libraries. (Of course Micro$oft fixes it with VC11)

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think MSVC comes bundled with any regex library.

Regex isn't part of the C/C++ standard library, so you shouldn't rely on any compiler providing such a library by default. It's best to get hold of a separate regex library for C (I'm sure there are tons available) and include it with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try Boost or wait for release of C++1x...

Comment: C, fwiw (need more characters)

Answer (score 0):

There's no C/C++ regexp library bundled with msvc. C++/CLI have access to the .NET regexp classes though.

Perhaps you can use [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want POSIX-compatible regular expression semantics (and the same API too!) then the best regex library is TRE: http://laurikari.net/tre/

Unlike most regex implementations, it follows POSIX exactly in regards to the matches it returns for parenthesized subexpressions, and it's `O(n)` whereas most implementations are `O(2^n)` in time.

Google also has a new regex implementation that uses Perl-compatible syntax if you prefer that. You can find a link on the TRE website.

Edit: By the way, TRE seems to come with project files to build it under MSVC.